# How can I make an HELM UPGRADE with specific tag container version?

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, harbor

I am trying through Azure DevOps to launch a Pipeline that specifies the label of a specific version of the container (not latest). How can I do that?

previously to this requirement, I used:

```
helm upgrade --values=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/<FOLDER/NAME>.yaml --namespace <NAMESPACE> --install --reset-values --wait <NAME> .
```

I am trying through Azure DevOps to launch a Pipeline that specifies the label of a specific version of the container (not latest). How can I do that?

At the moment, it gives me errors with the flag "--app-version":

```
2020-06-25T15:43:51.9947356Z Error: unknown flag: --app-version
2020-06-25T15:43:51.9990453Z 
2020-06-25T15:43:52.0054964Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Maybe, another way is download from the harbor repository and make a helm roll to a version with these TAG. But I can´t find the way. I can´t see that clear.

YML:

```
# Default values for consent-sandbox.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

replicaCount: 1

nameSpace: <NAME>-pre

image:
  repository: <REPO>
  pullPolicy: Always

## Uncomment and remove [] to download image private
imagePullSecrets: []
  # - name: <namePullSecret>
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: false
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name:

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

containers:
    portName: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP

env:
  APP_NAME: <NAME>
  JAVA_OPTS_EXT: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/truststore/jssecacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
  WILY_MOM_PORT: 5001
  TZ: Europe/Madrid
  spring_cloud_config_uri: https://<CONF>.local
  spring_application_name: <NAME>
  SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PROFILE: pre
  

envSecrets: {}

livenessProbe: {}
  # path: /
  # port: 8080

readinessProbe: {}
  # path: /
  # port: 8080

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  portName: http
  port: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  containerPort: 8080

secret:
  jks: <JKS>-jks
  jssecacerts: jssecacerts

ingress:
  enabled: false

route:
  enabled: true
  status: ""

  # Default values for openshift-route.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

  annotations:
  # kubernetes.io/acme-tls: "true"
  # haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout: 5000ms
  # haproxy.router.openshift.io/ip_whitelist: <IP>

  labels:

  host: "<HOST>.paas.cloudcenter.corp"
  path: ""

  wildcardPolicy: None

  nameOverride: ""
  fullnameOverride: ""

  tls:
    enabled: true
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: "None"
    key:
    certificate:
    caCertificate:
    destinationCACertificate:

  service:
    name: "<NAME"
    targetPort: http
    weight: 100

  alternateBackends: []


resources:
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  limits:
    cpu: 150m
    memory: 1444Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 1024Mi

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

Probably, I need add in the YML:

```
 containers:
  - name: my_container
    image: my_image:latest
    imagePullPolicy: "Always"
```

CHART:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: examplename
description: testing 

# A chart can be either an 'application' or a 'library' chart.
#
# Application charts are a collection of templates that can be packaged into versioned archives
# to be deployed.
#
# Library charts provide useful utilities or functions for the chart developer. They're included as
# a dependency of application charts to inject those utilities and functions into the rendering
# pipeline. Library charts do not define any templates and therefore cannot be deployed.
type: application

# This is the chart version. This version number should be incremented each time you make changes
# to the chart and its templates, including the app version.
version: 1.0.0

# This is the version number of the application being deployed. This version number should be
# incremented each time you make changes to the application.
appVersion: latest
```

but...what can I do if I can´t change the YML?

Comment: What Helm versio are you using. This is your chart or its official chart?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `Package and deploy Helm charts` task to change tag version in the image section of .yaml file? Is `--set container.tag=xxx` working for you?

Comment: Hi! I´m using Helm 3.1.1

I don´t want set other tag to existing container, I need make an upgrade commad with other container (in the same repository) with another tag version.

Comment: Are you able to provide which Helm Chart are you using and how your `values.yaml` looks like?

Comment: sure, post updated

Comment: Good example of values with specific tak you can find for example in [nginx ingress values](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml). Your values.yaml looks ok at first glance but there is nothing like `--app-version`. Are you using official repo or its somehting you have created by your own? Could you provide which Chart are you using? Maybe it was created for another cloud provider and contains some flags which are not recognized in Azure.

Comment: I´m using a private repo to download the artifact.
I don't want deploy the "latest" TAG, every time need deploy a different TAG on the infrastructure.

main post updated with the chart.

The issue is: How can I change via parameter the appVersion value on the chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use other way with OC client:

```
oc patch deploy push-engine --type='json' -p '[{ "op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/image", "value": "registry.sdi.dev.weu.azure.paas.cloudcenter.corp/test-dev/test:0.0.1" }]'
```